# Celery, rabbitmq: How to install remote worker?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

Can I have multiple machines to execute the tasks and return messages that are distributed by django? I looked into celery/rabbitmq, I'm not sure if I can setup celery workers on remote computers. Can anyone guide me through here? 
If this is not possible or very hard, any alternative solution for the problem?

Comment: did you figure it out?  I'm in the same boat.  I'm a unsure how to get the remote computer to be able to login to the database of the main computer to update the models

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by installing your Django project on to the remote computer, and then ensuring that it is configured to use the correct broker, database server, and media directory (assuming your tasks need access to that).

Comment: You can even do a *lean* worker-side installation, with just the essential bits (eg. just a `celeryconig.py` and a `tasks.py`). Just make sure that the Celery tasks are registered under the same name. (I've been using subfolders named like my apps–to mimic the task registry paths. I'm not sure if there's a way around that, though.)

Comment: You can specify the name manually as an argument to the `@task` decorator.